# Cannot load index to elasticsearch from external file, using logstash 1.4.2 on Windows 7

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

when trying to load a file into elastic, using logstash that is running the config file below, I get the following output msgs on elastic and no file is loaded (when input is configured to be stdin everything seems to be working just fine)

```
[2014-08-20 10:51:10,957][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Max] added {[logsta
  sh-GURWB02038-5480-4002][dstQagpWTfGkSU5Ya-sUcQ][GURWB02038][inet[/10.203.152.13
  9:9301]]{client=true, data=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(join from node[[l
ogstash-GURWB02038-5480-4002][dstQagpWTfGkSU5Ya-sUcQ][GURWB02038][inet[/10.203.1
52.139:9301]]{client=true, data=false}])
```

Logstash Config File that I used is below:-

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/example.log"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => "localhost" 
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you start elasticsearch?

Comment: I started elasticsearch using elasticsearch.bat file. I also tried to use embedded => true option in logstash conf file but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing start_position.

Try with something like this.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/example.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

Also take the "first contact" restriction into account, according to the documentation.

```
start_position
Value can be any of: "beginning", "end"
Default value is "end"
Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end.
The default behavior treats files like live streams and thus starts at the end.
If you have old data you want to import, set this to ‘beginning’

This option only modifies “first contact” situations where a file is new and not seen
before. If a file has already been seen before, this option has no effect.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From all the examples it seems that the syntext is:

```
output { 
 elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
}
```